# How to generate gcs files one after another with google cloud dataflow and java?

Tags: java, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, apache-beam-io

I have a pipeline with one gcs file as input and generate two gcs output files.
One output file contains error info and another contains normal info.
And I have a cloud function with the gcs trigger of the two output files.
I want to do something with the normal info file only when the error info file is 0 byte.
So I must let the error info file be generated earlier than the normal info file to check the size of the error info file.

Now I use 2 TextIO.Write to generate the two files.
But I can not control which one is generated first.
In the cloud functions, I let the normal info file check the size of the error info file with a retry.
But the cloud functions as a timeout limit of 540s so I can not retry until the error info file is generated.
How can I handle this in Cloud Dataflow?
Can I generate the error info file before the normal info file programmatically?

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish sequencing like this by using side inputs.  For example,

```
error_pcoll = ...
good_data_pcoll = ...

error_write_result = error_pcoll | beam.io.WriteToText(...)
(good_data_pcoll
 | beam.Map(
       # This lambda simply emits what it was given.
       lambda element, blocking_side: element,
       # This side input isn't used,
       # but will force error_write_result to be computed first.
       blocking_side=beam.pvalue.AsIterable(error_write_result))
 | beam.io.WriteToText(...))
```

The [Wait](https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/2.27.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/transforms/Wait.html) PTransform encapsulates this pattern.

Comment: I read the doc of "The Wait PTransform ". Sample code in doc ("Wait.on(firstWriteResults)" ) needs a parameter of PCollection, but the result of TextIO.Write  is PDone.

Comment: Oh, I forgot that Java's Write isn't this flexible. You could try using writeCustomType: https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/2.2.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/TextIO.html#writeCustomType--